# Javascript ES6: unable to change value of button with ajax (with the rest of the js code working fine)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ecmascript-6

My button:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Talk" class="btn btn-secondary" id="update-tlk" data-disable-with="Update Taaalk">
```

What's in my update.js file:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#update-tlk');
btn.value = "Updated";
btn.style = "background: red";
console.log(btn.value)
```

This is the code in my update.js.erb file and the button style is being set to red and the console is outputting "Updated", however my button is still set with the text "Update Talk", which I want to change to "Updated".

If I run

```
btn.value = "blaaa"
```

in the console then the visible text in the button changes to "blaaa".

My ajax code:

```
  def update
    if @spkr.user == current_user
      @spkr.update(spkr_params)
      complete_user_profile
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js # { @tlk }# <-- will render `app/views/reviews/create.js.erb`
        # format.html { redirect_to new_tlk_path(@tlk) } THIS LINE IS COMMENTED OUT!
      end
    else
      spkr_edited
      send_spkr_edited_mail
    end
  end
```

I have tried .innerText and .innerHTML and neither work.

I am using Ruby on Rails 6.

Comment: It should work as you wrote. I suppose you have something which overrides your value very fast... Check carefully from where that `Update Talk` text is coming.

Comment: Make sure the AJAX code is preventing default form submission, otherwise the page will reload with the original value.

Comment: Where’s the Ajax code?

Comment: Adding to the question now @evolutionxbox

Comment: Have you found the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is the "disable_with" feature you are using.

1. you submit the form
2. rails saves the current value "Update Talk"
3. rails changes the value to "Update Taaalk" (from your data-disable-with attribute)
4. you respond with some js that changes the value to "Updated"
5. rails reverts the "disable" states setting the old value "Update Talk"

Personally, I wouldn't change the value of the button (since it will still be clickable and it will submit the form again). I think it's better to hide the button and add the "Updated" message as another element.